# Pass php variable to exec

Tags: php

I need to get dimm info using ipmitool as follows:

```
exec("/usr/bin/ipmitool -I lan -H $spip -U root -P '$thepassword' sunoem cli 'show System/Memory/DIMMs/$a' | grep -i location", $dimm_loc, $ipmiretval);
```

$a is previously defined as:
 $a=$dimm[$i]

The return value for the above exec command is 1. If I replace $a with its vaule, i.e 
`exec("/usr/bin/ipmitool -I lan -H $spip -U root -P '$thepassword' sunoem cli 'show System/Memory/DIMMs/D5' | grep -i location", $dimm_loc, $ipmiretval);`

The exec command executes as expected. So it looks like $a cannot be used in the above example. How else can I pass the variable to the exec command?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `var_dump($a)` and see what actualy it contains. Also dump the executed command as a string to see if command is formated properly.

Comment: Thanks Bartosz!!! Yes there was extra spaces at the beginning of the string that needed to be trimmed!!! Thanks a ton!!.

Comment: Remember, `var_dump` is your closest friend when it comes to debug something :)

Answer (score 1):

One more tip.  Instead of doing an `exec("some very long command line")`, put your command line in a variable, then both LOG and exec() the variable.  For example:

```
$fmt="/usr/bin/ipmitool -I lan -H %s -U root -P '%s' sunoem cli 'show System/Memory/DIMMs/%s' | grep -i location";

$cmd=sprintf($fmt, $spip, $thepassword, $a);
exec($cmd, $dimm_loc, $ipmiretval);
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Running: $cmd");

if ($ipmiretval > 0) {
  syslog(LOG_ERR, "exec FAILED: $cmd");
} else {
  syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "exec: $cmd");
}
```