# exec command notworking in image magick php

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec

I am trying to join two images side by side using imagemagick.

```
        $in_file1 = escapeshellarg(trim($dir."_thumb/demo-".($r).".jpg"));
        $in_file2 = escapeshellarg(trim($dir."_thumb/demo-".($r+1).".jpg"));
        $out_put_file = escapeshellarg(trim($dir."_thumb/demo-horiz-".($i).".jpg"));
        //echo "convert  $in_file1 $in_file2 +append $out_put_file<hr/>";

        //$cmd = "convert ".$in_file1." ". $in_file2. " +append ".$out_put_file;
        //echo $cmd."<br/><hr/>";
        //exec("convert julycacae_thumb/demo-13.jpg julycacae_thumb/demo-14.jpg +append julycacae_thumb/demo-horiz-6.jpg"); 


            $fmt="convert %s %s +append %s";

            $cmd=sprintf($fmt, $in_file1, $in_file2, $out_put_file);
            echo $cmd."<br/><hr/>";
            exec($cmd, $dimm_loc, $ipmiretval);
            syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Running: $cmd");

            if ($ipmiretval > 0) {
              syslog(LOG_ERR, "exec FAILED: $cmd");
            } else {
              syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "exec: $cmd");
            }

        exec("convert julycdaad_thumb/demo-15.jpg julycdaad_thumb/demo-16.jpg +append julycdaad_thumb/demo-horiz-7.jpg"); 
        $r = $r+2;'
```

When i write the complete path of image in exec  it works but, on passing variables it doenot work ...

Comment: what does `syslog(LOG_ERR, "exec FAILED: $cmd");` print?

Comment: the problem is it is neither showing error :( you can see it working at http://catpops.in/future/convert.php

Comment: i don't see `$ipmiretval` being set anywhere, so why would it?

Comment: when i write the output in exec it works as exec("convert julycdaad_thumb/demo-15.jpg julycdaad_thumb/demo-16.jpg +append julycdaad_thumb/demo-horiz-7.jpg");  but if i pass variable like : exec($cmd, $dimm_loc, $ipmiretval); it doent work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369071/pass-php-variable-to-exec took refernce from here ... before that when i was working only with exec .. then also it was not working

Comment: so `exec($cmd);` isn't working? you have `//$cmd = "convert ".$in_file1." ". $in_file2. " +append ".$out_put_file;` commented out... does that line work? instead of syslog why don't you try `var_dump()`?

Comment: no :( i am stuck from last 72 hours

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use that??? means where??

Comment: when you said " no :( ..." I had no idea what you were responding to. I asked like 3 questions. When you're asking "how can I use that???" I have no idea what you're talking about, be more specific. I'd like to help but you have to help me help you equally.

Comment: dear sir, the thing is im a beginer and i just want to use exec but when i pass variables the exec doent seems to work and thats my problem . also tell me how can i use var_dump in above case rather then syslog???? i have searched plenty of resources but i was unable to get ay idea ??